# REST-endpoint address naming approach

Tags: rest

In my project I have a `Team` entity. Its structure looks like that:

```
id: long; // primary key
teamNumber: string; // unique team number, numeric, but can contain leading zeroes
title: string; // team title
```

I have a REST-endpoint to get team by id, and the address of this endpoint name pattern looks like that:

```
/teams/{id}
```

So, if I want to get a team by its id, for example for id=123, I make the GET-request to:

```
/teams/123
```

But, also it is required to have an endpoint to get a team by team number (not id).

And in this case I can't have a REST-endpoint with the same pattern:

```
/teams/{teamNumber}
```

Because it conflicts with the

```
/teams/{id}
```

I should have another unique address for this (get) request.

My question: what is the best practice to name REST-endpoint addresses for such cases?

Should I have something like:

```
/teams/team-by-number/{teamNumber}
```

Or there is a better approach?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this conflicting case, according to the [conventions](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/), I'd recommend:

1. `/teams/id/{id}`
2. `/teams/team-number/{teamNumber}`

Comment: If your domain requires you to have a distinguished identification - sometimes with `id` and sometimes with `team-number`, then you definitely have to create two sub-resources (namespaces) like provided in the example.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 unique ways to find these resources, and both can potentially collide (they're both numbers), then yes you will definitely need 2 different namespaces.

Your approach to this is fine.

I *would* question if you can't just use one of the two, because I can imagine that having 2 unique numeric identifiers can easily confuse people. If this is a hard requirement, then I think you're on the right path.

Comment: In some cases I import teams information, and I have only team numbers, not ids.
'id:long' is auto-generated primary key. 'number:string' - is a just team number with arbitrary number with leading zeroes. Do you think it is a good idea to declare`number:string` a primary key?

Comment: @Rafael, well.. if you are importing these teams and they're also always unique.. you might consider just using that. In your database you could still use an auto-incremented id for easy reference between tables, but yes.. if you can I would attempt to remove one of the two id's at least from your API.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you are using is called `path parameter`. You can also use `query parameters`. Something like below:

`/teams?id=123 or /teams?teamNumber=123`

This is just another way. It's up to you.

Comment: You're right, using named query parameters would solve the issue. But I would like to preserve my described approach. I think it looks better and cleaner (I may be wrong for sure).

Comment: What you are using is definitely correct. But query parameters are also standards one for get, if information is not sensitive. What if you have such more paths? Will you be creating more GET resources for each and replicate same piece of code?

Comment: From Client perspective also, for different kind of GETs in this case, they will have to call different URIs.

Comment: it is a get-request, so I can use query-parameters as well. There won't be more paths, the class structure is defined and won't be updated. And I have just a few rest-endpoints for the task. Amount of these endpoints won't grow in the nearest future as far as I know. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's ok @Rafael. But when we design, we need to think all of this even though we see that it's not gonna change in near future. In real scenarios, requirement can change any time. Anyways, your choice. All the best.